# compare CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with integer

Tags: php, database, web

Hi i wonder how to compare CURRENT_TIMESTAMP value with an int , I have a int value in table book lets say it is called b_time and I have a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP value in table subscriber lets say it is called s_time , b_time is the time that a book is allowed to be borrowed lets say  5 means 5 days , s_time is the time the subscriber borrowed the book , the role is if there is 2 days left to the end of the book allowed borrowing time (b_time) something will happen ,so i want to compare s_time with b_time, this is my idea but i don't know how to implement it even in the database table declaration :

(php)

```
$t = b_time-2 ;
if (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() == s_time+$t) {
    //do somthing
}
```

i know this will not run but i wnt a code that do the same thing .

thanks .

Comment: Testing for equality is always a bad thing with times.

Comment: You might consider using MySQL's date-add() function.

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` isn't a PHP function it's an SQL function and needs to be used in a query and not as defined like you have it now and error reporting would throw you an `undefined CURRENT_TIMESTAMP constant` notice about it. Your question is unclear/too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Use `time()` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php
or use DateTime class http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php, for example:

```
$dateTime  = new DateTime('now');
$timeStamp = $dateTime->format('U');
```

"U" - Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)

**Update#1**:
Check if there is 2 days left to the end of the book allowed:

```
$dateTime         = new DateTime('now');
$dateTimeBookLeft = new DateTime($b_time);

$interval  = $dateTime->diff($dateTimeBookLeft);
$countDays = $interval->d;
if ($counDays == 2) {
   ...
}
```

**Update#2**

```
$currentDate = new DateTime('now'); //current date
$b_issued    = new DateTime('2015-12-08 10:00:00');  //date when the book was issued
$b_time      = 5; //number of days for which has been given a book
$interval    = $b_issued->diff($currentDate);
$b_left_days =  $b_time - $interval->d;

if ($b_left_days == 2) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: $dateTimeBookLeft = new DateTime($b_time); what it will do , note b_time is integer what it will do with the integer value what $dateTimeBookLeft will be if b_time was 5.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have confused. Check my update with comments

Answer (score 0):

first fetch the time at which book is borrowed i.e. s_time and store it as $s_time

now fetch the book allowed borrow days i.e. b_time and store it as $b_time

now compare if current book borrowed has less than two days to return to library

so comparison logic will be

```
if(time() >=  $s_time + (($b_time - 2) * 86400) ) ) {

   //this means borrowed book has two days to return now


}
```

Comment: in data base the time at which book is borrowed type is date means    2015-01-01  how can i compare book allowed borrow days integer with that value  2015-01-01 + ((5 - 2)  i think that doesn't work.

Comment: you can use strtotime() function of php to convert datetime to unix timestamp.

so 
$s_time = strtotime($s_time);
$b_time = strtotime($b_time);

and then above logic